# Конфигурирование позиции текста в Label

Tags: python, tkinter

Столкнулся с необходимостью конфигурирования позиции текста в Label. Может кому-то будет полезно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отнаследоваться от `tk.Frame`, то не нужно будет создавать свои методы pack/place/grid. Метод `place` для метки достаточно вызывать один раз внутри метода `__init__`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import RIGHT, CENTER

root = tk.Tk()


class ALabel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=24, height=24, bg='#F2F2F2', kx=0, ky=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, width=width, height=height, bg=bg)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, bg=bg, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label.place(anchor=CENTER, x=width/2+kx, y=height/2+ky)


close = ALabel(root, text='', font=('Lucida', 12), ky=-2)
close.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: я забыл про 'super().__init__' ... поэтому и не получилось. спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(P.S. смещение текста за счет kx и ky)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import RIGHT, CENTER

root = tk.Tk()

class ALabel():
    def __init__(self, parent, width=24, height=24, bg='#F2F2F2', kx=0, ky=0, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = width
        self.y = height
        self.kx = kx
        self.ky = ky

        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent, width=width, height=height, bg=bg)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, bg=bg, *args, **kwargs)

    def label_place(self):
        self.label.place(anchor=CENTER, x=self.x/2+self.kx, y=self.y/2+self.ky)

    def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.pack(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_place()

    def place(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.place(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_place()

    def grid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.grid(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_place()

close = ALabel(root, text='', font=('Lucida', 12), ky=-2)
close.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Нужно было всего лишь отнаследовать ALabel от Frame, тогда не нужно было бы реализовывать собственные методы pack/place/grid.

Comment: insolor, а куда тогда пихать self.label.place ?

Comment: В `__init__`. У вас положение не меняется (по крайней мере в приведенном коде), поэтому place достаточно один раз вызвать.

Comment: insolor, у меня идет обращение через ALabel к tk.Label, если я наследуюсь от Frame, тогда и переменные от ALabel идут в tk.Frame, а не в tk.Label. Честно говоря у меня поправить не получилось, можете работающий код предоставить 'как ответ' ?